# Placement of background image not remaining ok with the contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting background image working properly. Here is my test page URL link

[swagatobhatta.com/test/](http://swagatobhatta.com/test/)

Now as you can see that it has a background image...
which can be located at here

[image]

The problem is

- When you resize the window, the image does not move along with the box that contains the form properly
- Also, I am having lots of trouble getting the bg image show up exactly like the jpeg image shown....that is the placement....any ideas please?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.15081.js"></script>
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="desktopBody">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="col-sm-2 logo"> <a href=""  target="_blank" title="Virgin Mobile"><img src="images/logo_virginMobile.png" alt="" class="img-responsive text-right"/></a> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 thankYou"> <img src="images/txt_THANKYOU.png" alt="THANK YOU" class="img-responsive text-right "/> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="menu-outer">
          <div class="table">
            <ul class="menu"  id="horizontal-list">
              <li class="first"><a href="http://www.virginmobile.com.au/privacy/" target="_blank" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy policy</a></li>
              <li class="second"><a href="#" title="Terms and Conditions" target="_blank" >Terms and Conditions</a></li>
              <li class="last"><a href="http://www.virginmobile.com.au/contact-virgin-mobile/" target="_blank" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="body">
      <h1 class="specialGift col-sm-12">A special gift just for you...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="form">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="submitDetails" action="choseGiftpage.html" method="POST" id="submitDetails"  autocomplete="off" onload="ClearForm()">
          <legend>Thanks for being a great<br/>
          customer, you rock! </legend>
          <fieldset  class="virgin">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <input value=""  id="virginMobileNumber" name="virginMobileNumber" type="text" placeholder="Virgin Mobile Number" class="form-control input-md virginMobileNumber"/>
                <span class="error">Oops - please enter your mobile number</span> </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <input value=""  id="giftRedemtionCode" name="giftRedemtionCode" type="text" placeholder="Gift redemption code" class="form-control input-md giftRedemtionCode"/>
                <span class="error">Oops - please enter gift redemption code</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divTwo">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 captcha"><img src="images/captchaPlaceholder.png" alt="captcha" /></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 captchaText">
                <input value=""  id="captchaText" name="captchaText" type="text" placeholder="Type characters on left" class="form-control input-md captchaText"/>
                <span class="error">Oops - please enter character</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divTwo">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mandatoryText">All fields are mandatory</div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 submitButton">
                 <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn  sr-only" title="CHOOSE YOUR GIFT" type="submit">CHOOSE YOUR GIFT ></button>
                <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn submit" title="CHOOSE YOUR GIFT" type="submit">CHOOSE YOUR GIFT ></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #626366;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("../images/bg_body.png") no-repeat scroll 60% 121% #FAFAFA;
    max-width: 1400px
}
.form {
}
a {
    color: #626366;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #6b1f7c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.error {
    color: #e11f27;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-style: italic
}
h1 {
    color: #2d2d2d;
    font-family: "ProximaNova_ltlight", Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 4.2em;
}
h1.specialGift {
    margin-top: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center
}
.mandatoryText{
    color: #7b7b7d;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:33px;

}
.container {
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
    max-width: 1400px;
}
.header {
    max-width: 685px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.thankYou {
    margin-top: 3%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu {
    list-style: none;
}
.header li a {
    font-family: "ProximaNova_ltlight", Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    float: left;
    color: #626366;
    margin-top: 2%
}
.first a {
    margin-left: 17.5%;
    margin-right: 31px;
}
.second a {
    margin-right: 27px
}
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0px
}
form {
    max-width: 510px;
    height: 353px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: none #f1edea;
    border: 2px solid #e5e1de;
    padding-left: 34px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-top: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
}
legend {
    color: #692789;
    font-family: "ProximaNova_ltlight", Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 2.903em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #a1a1a1;
}
.form-control:focus, .form-control:hover {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.form-control.giftRedemtionCode{
    background:url("../images/question.png") no-repeat scroll 97% center #ffffff;
}
.virgin .col-sm-12 {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.virgin div:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.virgin div+div {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.virgin .col-sm-12.divTwo {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.submit,.submit:hover,.submit:focus,.submit:active {
    background: url(../images/btn_gift.png) no-repeat 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 100%;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: can you show your markup??html and css???

Comment: @Himu : so you want to keep the `body background image` in its position irrespective of browser width??

Comment: not really. When browser width decreases, the background image should move along with the form box... Then, when form box stats to scale down, the background image should also scale down.Aka the background image should move and scale along with the form box or the contents of the page....how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the image as bg for body, add thsi to your body attribute css

```
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position : center center;
```

Here is a demo  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/teks9/1/)

**But**, going by the design of your page, my suggestion would be to set a `color` for the body and add this `bg` to your `form` class, like :

```
body {
       font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #626366;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1400px;
        background-color:#FAFAFA; /*assign body color*/
   }

  .form {
        background: url("http://swagatobhatta.com/test/images/bg_body.png") no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: contain;
        -moz-background-size: contain;
        -o-background-size: contain;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position : center center;
        width:100%; /*give full available width to form*/
    }
```

This will give you bg a more optimal place to expand a adjust according to your form class on varying browser widths!!